# Having a C# method return more than one value of different data types?

Tags: c#

I have a function which takes two parameters:

```
 string[], double[]
```

How do I return both of these values?  How do call that function?

Comment: it's possible in Mono C#, don't know if it will trickle down to future Microsoft's C#

Comment: Hao: please give a pointer or show an example.

Comment: OK, it turns out that there's a proof of concept that allows unpacking assignment for tuples: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-23.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hey you can use the keyword "out":

```
column s1;
column s2;

public void method1(out value1, out value2)
{
select col1, col2, from tb1
value1 = col1;
value2 = col2;
}
```

Comment: That's one of the reasons out was made.

Answer (score 11):

Create an object with properties for the values you want to return:

```
public class MyReturnType
{
    public string[] MyStringArray { get; set; }
    public double[] MyDoubleArray { get; set; }
}
```

Your method would then return this new type:

```
public MyReturnType Foo()
{
    ...
    return new MyReturnType { MyStringArray = strings; MyDoubleArray = doubles; };
}
```

Comment: imho should only be used when the return values are related (big chance that they are because they come from the same function)

Answer (score 7):

- Use a Tuple structure (new in .NET 4.0, but you can just make one up in your own dll based on it - it is a simple container for multiple generic types).
- Use a specialized carrier structure like Michael Shimmins answer says, but make it a struct, not a class, unless it is large.
- Use a dicitonary or an array of object, if that is a purely internal function (case issues).
- Use out parameters.

Comment: Nope, sorry - a book about the basics of C# or the documentation have all the examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the out or ref parameter.

See [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/out_and_ref11112005002102AM/out_and_ref.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you cant return this directly but you can return this using strct. you can create struct for string and double and store the value in it,after that you can return it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ref operator

Answer (score -3):

You could return a `Hashtable` of objects. Or a `List`... or any sort of object collection you want.

LE:

```
Hashtable process(string[] x, double[] y)
{
   Hashtable output = new Hashtable();

   // do whatever you want with x and y

   output["stringArray"] = x;
   output["doubleArray"] = y;
   return output;
}

// ...

string[] stringArray = new string[] {};
double[] doubleArray = new double[] {};

// ...

Hashtable outcome = process(stringArray, doubleArray);
string[] data1 = (string[])outcome["stringArray"];
double[] data2 = (double[])outcome["doubleArray"];

// ...
```

Comment: only hashtable usefull when returning different types (due no type safety)

Comment: how to call that function at different location??

Comment: Is this really a better solution than void MyFunc(out string[] x, out double[] y);  ?